# He's likely to succeed

Tags: pronouns

According to the book of Michael Swan *Practical English Usage*:

> Be +likely is often followed by infinitive. (Probable cannot be used in this way).
>
> - *I am likely to be busy tomorrow*.
> - *Are you likely to be staying in this evening*.
> - *Do you think it is likely to rain?*
> - *He is unlikely to agree*.
>
> ***It*** is not used as a preparatory subject in this structure.
>
> - *He's likely to succeed*. (**NOT** It is likely for him to succeed.)

Could you please clarify about the last two line?
I think we are not allowed to use this format:

> 'it is likely ... to ..'

but:

> 'The Environment Agency has warned that it is likely to be an ongoing problem.'

As we know, 'It is likely to rain' is grammatically correct, but we used 'it' as a subject in above sentence. And it is the opposition of Michael Swan book.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In your example, 'it' is a regular pronoun, referring to some subject introduced earlier (such as 'air pollution').

So the sentence is perfectly grammatical.

> *(...some sentence introducing the topic of air pollution.)*  The Environment Agency has warned that *air pollution* is likely to be an ongoing problem.